# How to create DB2 sql dump from WebSphere Application server ?

Tags: database, postgresql, jboss, websphere

I am using `WebSphere application server` for deploying my `EAR` Application . I have `DB2` Database in that server . Now i am trying to Deploy same Application on `Jboss` application server with `PostgreSQL`. I need to change the existing `DB2` database to `PostgreSQL` . I have researched about this topics and finally i got some useful tools .

https://github.com/dalibo/db2topg
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL

Now i want `SQL dump` of my DB2 schema for converting `DB2` to `PostgreSQL` . I want to know whether can i get SQL dumps of DB2 from the application server of WebSphere ? Or any other methods to convert DB2 to PostgreSQL ? Any suggestion will be helpful to me to solve this problem .

Answer (score 1):

No, WebSphere Application Server does not provide a general means to export the schema of a DB2 database.  A google search for ***export db2 schema*** will provide you multiple ways to do it using DB2.  Again a google search for ***convert schema from db2 to postgres*** yields numerous tools to migrate schemas including a postgres wiki.